(blocked:mixed-content) from cloudfront to ec2
My frontend is hosted on aws cloudfront and backend on ec2, while trying to singin from frontend I'm facing (blocked:mixed-content) The page at 'https://.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
I have create a new Origin request policy and Response headers policy also updated the protocols from http to https to http and https but still facing the same issue.
however, when I deploy the frontend on ec2 it's working fine.
